# How do I access my passwords from `pass` from another computer without transferring private GPG keys?

Tags: git, gpg, synchronization, password-store

I recently learned about `pass` git integration, which allows to sync my passwords with a remote git repo. Which I instantly didn't hesitate to configure.

So then I decided to clone this repo on another computer (with another GPG key installed) and try to access the passwords. It however complained:

```
pass myaccount
gpg: decryption failed: no secret key
```

I guess that comes from the fact that I have another GPG key installed, not the one I encrypted my passwords with (I use the same GPG key ID though).

So, how do I access those passwords without transferring private GPG keys from the original machine to this one? I of course know the passphrase, and can transfer public ones if needed.

Or am I required to copy over the whole keyring?

#### Thoughts...

Now after writing this post, I think I'm closer to understanding how it works. So basically the keys I can find in `~/.gnupg` aren't just keys - they are *encrypted* keys. Encrypted with the passphrase. And so it's relatively safe to copy them to another machine. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't tried it myself, but `pass` should be able to encrypt passwords for multiple GPG keys, so transfer the public key from the second computer to the first, and run `pass init <id-of-GPG-key-1> <id-of-GPG-key-2>`, then `pass` should encrypt all passwords in your store that aren't encrypted for those two keys for them, and (when synced, that's something `git` is good for) then they should be useable on both computers.

If you can't remember the id of the key that passwords are currently encrypted for, you can look in `<password-store>/.gpgid`.

Comment: So, is it right that I need to have both public keys on both computers? (but private keys stay where they are)

Comment: Yes (as said I still haven't tried, but that's my understanding).

Comment: Hmm, thanks. But then every newly added device means I have to re-encrypt them all on all devices, right?

Comment: Alright, it works. I [made a step-by-instruction](https://gist.github.com/WhiteBlackGoose/8ffb7123b991dcc4cdafcdd574bdc3c6#22-add-new-computer)

Comment: If I understand this right, when I am adding my 5th computer, so I'll have to go around all the other 4 to add to all of them my 5th public key? That also does not seem ideal. Also I have doubts that my Android pass client actually supports that. In my opinion the GPG keys are meant to be per physical person and not per machine. So personally, I send around with my single private key, protected by the passphrase. Once the key is installed on a particular device, so often the device offers some kind of secure storage that allows me to get rid of the passphrase locally.

Comment: For every new GPG key it should only be necessary to re-encrypt passwords once. Then on the computer where you did that, you'll `git push` the repository, and if you then get `.gpgid` updated (e.g. by running `git pull` in the repo) on an machine before you add a password on that machine, that password will also be encrypted for the new computer (and if you don't `git` will probably at least warn you that copy is behind when you try to push the repo.